# Capturing generic parameters in mapped types

Tags: typescript, generics, mapped-types

In typescript I'd like to use generic parameters that aren't a part of the signature. For example, I would like some code like the following...

```
type NotArray<T> = T extends Array<I> ? I: T;
type Test1 = NotArray<Array<number>>; // Resolves to 'number'
type Test2 = NotArray<string>> // Resolves to 'string'
```

This fails to compile with `Cannot find name 'I'.` If I change `I` to `any`, it will compile, but then the resolved type is `any`. Eg:

```
type NotArray<T> = T extends Array<any> ? any: T;
type Fail = NotArray<Array<number>>; // Resolves to 'any'
```

Is there a way to 'capture' the generic parameter to the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `infer` keyword before `I` definition:

```js
type NotArray<T> = T extends Array<infer I> ? I: T;
type Test1 = NotArray<Array<number>>; // Resolves to 'number'
type Test2 = NotArray<string> // Resolves to 'string'
```

See [Type inference in conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#type-inference-in-conditional-types)

Comment: A link to the [relevant documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#type-inference-in-conditional-types)